# Has any philosophy in history coherently disambiguated the state of being “real” from being “existent”? Such that it’s broadly applicable to thoughts?

Tags: epistemology, existence, reality

I suspect that things which simply exist are not bound by limits and are hence unlimited. According to economic thinking, real things are those which are scarce or limited by constraints of physical reality and progressive expiry. Looking for further conjectures that can disambiguate what’s real from what exists.

Comment: It doesn’t quite. A software simply exists in a computer but isn’t real. To be real you have to be limited by the constraints of reality, entropy and expiring progression. We are real like the earth you stand because reality is our plane of existence unlike a software existing in a computer.

Comment: In philosophy what you call "real" is actually classified as *ontology (commitment)* in an essentialist's way and the difference with "existence" is often conflated with our everyday classic logic but can be further studied and carefully compared in [free logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_logic)...

Comment: You’re right this disambiguation attempt could be referred to as an ontological exercise. The concept of free logic is interesting to me. Would you say it to an extent refers to pure philosophy?

Comment: Indeed it could be said to be part of pure philosophy and SEP also has a long article about the [same](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/) to refer further. Generally speaking logic is a first course and a pre-taste of any serious (pure) philosophy...

Comment: Logic is the true master in my opinion. We can only tend towards it. Honesty with logic evolves into wisdom.

Comment: Exist and real have many meanings in philosophy and language. Compare with the word 'set' which I recall reading thirty years ago had over 200 meanings in the English Language. When words have that many meanings we are not here to do your "disambiguating" for you. We expect people to do a bit of research themselves.

Comment: I am attempting to disambiguate a generalized meaning for “real” and “exist”. The best way I could distinguish them is firstly everything that is real exists, with reality as a medium and are limited by constraints of reality such as entropy and progressive expiry/subsistence. What simply “exists” require a medium to process their existence, abstract unlimited things merely exist, but tangible and limited things objectively exist in reality and are hereby real.

Answer (score 1):

For an object to be "real" it must exist and be authentic. A "real" Picasso vs a fake: Two paintings that both "exist" but only one is "real".

Comment: Real in that sense is as opposed to fake. But real in the sense I described is as opposed to unreal to give us a deeper insight to disambiguate with.

Comment: Real things exist in reality. Things which simply exist require a medium in reality to hold them besides reality itself.

Comment: I consider reality to be a subset of existence. For example, dreams and ideas exist but are not real.

Answer (score 1):

Kant distinguished the real from the existent, as described by Heidegger in *The Basic Problems of Phenomenology*, Chapter One [Kant's Thesis: Being Is Not A Real Predicate](https://books.google.gg/books?id=VmatHCLJ4Q4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 34

> The concept of reality and the real in Kant does not have the meaning
> most often intended nowadays when we speak of the reality of the
> external world or of epistemological realism. Reality is not
> equivalent to actuality, existence, or extantness. It is not identical
> with existence, although Kant indeed uses the concept "objective
> reality" identically with existence.
>
> The Kantian meaning of the
> term "reality" is the one that is appropriate to the literal sense of
> the word. In one place Kant translates "reality" very fittingly by
> "thingness," "thing-determinateness." The real is what pertains  to
> the res. When Kant talks about the omnitudo realitatis, the totality
> of all realities, he means not the whole of all beings actually extant
> but, just the reverse, the whole of all possible thing-determinations,
> the whole of all thing-contents or real-contents, essences, possible
> things. Accordingly, realitas is synonymous with Leibniz' term
> possibilitas, possibility. Realities are the what-contents of possible
> things in general without regard to whether or not they are actual, or
> "real" in our modern sense. The concept of reality is equivalent to
> the concept of the Platonic idea as that pertaining to a being  which
> is understood when I ask: Ti esti, *what* is the being?

So in the Kantian sense we may consider a nutritious, red (both predicates) apple (idea/essence).  It is a possible real(ity), not necessarily actual. (Incidentally, *omnitudo realitatis* "all possible things" and possible dangers are what we have to look out for and think of negotiating blind corners and explorations in our everyday worlds.  It's not a fiction, so to speak.)

Kant holds that actuality is not a *description* that can attach to the idea of the apple, page 36:

> Thus he speaks of the concept of a thing and puts in brackets "of a
> real," which does not mean of an actual. For reality means the
> affirmatively posited predicate having real content. Every predicate
> is at bottom a real predicate. Therefore Kant's thesis reads: Being is
> not a real predicate, that is, being in general is not a predicate of
> any thing at all.

Kant sees actuality emerging from the combination of mind and thing, page 92:

> Kant wishes to avoid conceiving of actuality, existence, itself as a
> res; he does this by interpreting existence as *relation* to the
> cognitive faculty, hence treating perception as position.

So colourful green ideas are real (as possibilities), but if they are thought, they are *actual* colourful green ideas.